# Justification for substituting "Itô differentials"

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, itos-lemma, differential-equations, proof

I'm reading Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance, Volume II*. In it, he uses the stochastic differential notation. For example, he may write

$$\mathrm{d}X(t) = \sigma(t)\mathrm{d}W(t)+\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t\tag{ 1}$$

to mean (formally)

$$\int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1}\mathrm{d}X(t) = \int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1}\sigma(t)\mathrm{d}W(t)+\int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1}\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t\text{.}\tag{2}$$

This is fine and makes sense. The problem is that he will often substitute the LHS of $(1)$ for the RHS of $(1)$ in other stochastic differential equations. For example, given the function $S(t)$, he may use $(1)$ to justify the equality

$$S(t) \mathrm{d}X(t) = S(t)\sigma(t)\mathrm{d}W(t)+S(t)\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t\text{,}\tag{3}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1} S(t) \mathrm{d}X(t) = \int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1} S(t)\sigma(t)\mathrm{d}W(t)+\int_{t=s_0}^{t=s_1} S(t)\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t\text{.}\tag{4}$$

This trick appears to be purely symbolic. Intuitively, it makes sense. However, I am having trouble proving that you can make this substitution. Is there a proof that you can make these kinds of substitutions (in this example or in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where in the book Shreve justifies (3) directly from (1). But he would have almost surely referred to the *discretized* versions of the "differentials". That is:

$$ X(t_{i+1})-X(t_{i}) \approx \sigma(t_i)(W(t_{i+1})-W(t_{i}))+\alpha(t_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_{i}) $$

implies
$$ S(t_{i})(X(t_{i+1})-X(t_{i})) \approx S(t_{i})\sigma(t_i)(W(t_{i+1})-W(t_{i}))+S(t_{i})\alpha(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_{i}). $$

We would *then* take summations and limits (needed in an integration mechanism) on both sides and justify why a stochastic integral wrt to *an Ito process integrator* can be *defined* as in (4), which is *Definition 4.4.5* in the book, given *after* Shreve had already defined stochastic integrals wrt to $W(t)$ and $t$ integrators.

Comment: "I don't see where..." This question is based on (4.4.27), but a better example is from (5.2.20) to (5.2.22). I don't consider this an answer to the question because I am looking for a proof.

Comment: Proof of what? (2) and (4) are both definitions, one defines the integrator, the other defines the integral wrt that integrator.

Comment: (4.4.27) is a formal application of Ito-Doeblin 4.4.6 for (functions of) Ito processes (generalizing 4.4.1) to $f(x)=S(0)\exp(x)$, with  $X(t)$ Ito process and $S(t)=f(X(t))$.

Comment: Once one also accepts (4.8.12), the multidimensional Ito-Doeblin theorem, and its consequence (a couple of phrases below it) the Ito's product rule, derivations like (5.2.20), $d(D(t)S(t))$, come relatively easy (you can, of course, post them as separate questions, if you think the application of Ito-Doeblin doesn't seem straightforward). [They are not a matter of stochastic integral definitions, in formal or informal shapes.]